# this context of public property is Undefined inside Map operator in Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular, this, observable

I am implementing the code shown below:

```
isValidLogin():Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get(this._checkLoginUrl)
       .map(res=>res.json())
        .map((res) => {
            if (res.success) {
                this.loggedIn = true;
            }
            return res;
        });

}
```

Transpiled Js:

```
  LoginService.prototype.isValidLogin = function () {
    var _this = this;
    return this.http.get(this._checkLoginUrl)
        .map(function (res) { return res.json(); })
        .map(function (res) {
        if (res.success) {
            _this.loggedIn = true;
        }
        return res;
    });
};
```

Here the `loggedIn` is a public property of the class, but it shows `undefined` and `this`here became the Map object context, and it is not able to assign value to `loggedIn`.

I think the lambda expression should be able to access this context of class object.
Is there something I have done wrong here?

Comment: I think it is to do with how lambda infers this. When you use this it lexical infers this form enclosing function and in this case it is map function (1st one)

Comment: Can you look at transpiled ja code. That will give more correct picture. Feel free to add that here as well

Comment: thank you @ArpitAgarwal for the reply please see my updated code with transpiled one . It is with the expected code for context in JS. If I  use another variable for this context outside of function it works even in Typescript but I think it is not needed in TS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the lambda expression should be able to access this context of class object. Is there something I have done wrong here

The class member probably needs to an arrow as well. Instead of :

```
isValidLogin():Observable<boolean> {
```

Write:

```
isValidLogin = ():Observable<boolean> => {
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: thanks it works , I was unaware of the  use of arrow in class member, nice article